# How do I enumerate all time zones in .NET?

Tags: timezone

I would like to have a list of all the time zones available on a Windows Machine. How can I do this in .NET?

I know about the TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones method, but this returns only the currently selected time zone(s)

```cs
DateTimeOffset current = DateTimeOffset.Now;
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
Console.WriteLine("You might be in the following time zones:");
foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
{
   // Compare offset with offset for that date in that time zone
   if (timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(current).Equals(current.Offset))
   {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", timeZoneInfo.DisplayName);
   }
}
```

Comment: Suffering from cut-n-paste-itis? :) You're already iterating through the whole enumeration but filtering away the offsets that isn't the same as the current one with the if-statement.

Comment: I overlooked the if in the code :(

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No it doesn't, it returns every time zone the Windows machine knows about (in my installation, that's 91). The `if` statement you have there is what is limiting your output. Take that out but leave the `Console.WriteLine` part, and you'll see all 91 (or so) timezones.

e.g.

```cs
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", timeZoneInfo.DisplayName);
```

That should write out 91 timezones to your console.

Comment: `timeZones.Count` = ***135***

Comment: Just for additional info, there is a native windows tool to print all timezones : `tzutil /l` if you need a list right away

Answer (score 5):

Your code works fine for me. Here's the output on my box:

> You might be in the following time
>   zones:    (GMT) Casablanca    (GMT)
>   Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin,
>   Edinburgh, Lisbon, London    (GMT)
>   Monrovia, Reykjavik

That's all the ones with the same offset at the moment, which is what your code clearly displays - if you want *all* the timezones, just remove the "if" part, as Robert says.

If you think you should be seeing more zones, could you tell us which timezone you're in so we can work out what other ones should be displayed?

Answer (score 4):

This method is used to bind all timezones in Dev express Drop Down.
I hope it will help for Someone.

```cs
private void FillTimeZone(ASPxComboBox ddlTimeZone)
{   
   ddlTimeZone.DataSource = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();   
   ddlTimeZone.DataBind();  
   ListEditItem oListEditItem=new ListEditItem();   
   oListEditItem.Text=Helper.SELECT;   
   oListEditItem.Value=Helper.SELECT;   
   ddlTimeZone.Items.Add(oListEditItem);   
   ddlTimeZone.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If wanting a json output from a WebAPI call:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class TimeZoneViewModel
    {
        public readonly List<CTimeZone> CTimeZones;

        public TimeZoneViewModel()
        {
            CTimeZones = new List<CTimeZone>();
            foreach (TimeZoneInfo z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
            {
                var tz = new CTimeZone(z.Id, z.DisplayName, z.BaseUtcOffset);
                CTimeZones.Add(tz);
            }
        }

    }

    public class CTimeZone
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan BaseUtcOffset { get; set; }

        public CTimeZone(string id, string displayName, TimeSpan utcOffset)
        {
            Id = id;
            DisplayName = displayName;
            BaseUtcOffset = utcOffset;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in WebAPI:

```cs
[HttpGet("Api/TimeZones")]
public JsonResult GetTimeZones()
{
    return Json(new TimeZoneViewModel().CTimeZones);
}
```

Output:

```json
[{
    "id": "Dateline Standard Time",
    "displayName": "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West",
    "baseUtcOffset": "-12:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "UTC-11",
    "displayName": "(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11",
    "baseUtcOffset": "-11:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "Aleutian Standard Time",
    "displayName": "(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands",
    "baseUtcOffset": "-10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "Hawaiian Standard Time",
    "displayName": "(UTC-10:00) Hawaii",
    "baseUtcOffset": "-10:00:00"
  },...
```