# Possible to find TimeZoneById with TimeZoneDisplayName?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using asp.net mvc and I am using a method that was on this site.

[How do I enumerate all time zones in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442019/how-do-i-enumerate-all-time-zones-in-net)

So this is what I doing. I then display the results to the user. The user picks their timezone and I saved the display name in the database.

However I am now trying to actually do time zone conversion.

I am trying to do it like this(I am not sure if this is the right way to do it though).

```
  TimeZoneInfo zoneInfo  = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(id);
  var time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now, zoneInfo);
```

So I think this would be right it gets the system time and the users time zone and uses this information to convert it to the local UTC time.

So assuming this is all right what I done(if not please correct me) the problem I am facing is how do I get the Id?

I have no clue how to find the id. Like I am willing to save the ID instead of the DisplayName in the database but I have no clue how to figure out the ID from the DisplayName.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps cache them at startup in a dictionary:

```
static readonly Dictionary<string, TimeZoneInfo> zones
    = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToDictionary(z => z.DisplayName);
```

Then fetch as `zones[displayName]` (or via `zones.TryGetValue(displayName, out zone)` if you want to be safe).

Comment: Yup, that's a much better idea than fetching them in a linear way.

Comment: @Jon - I think your points about "Saving the ID instead of the display name would be a good idea" are valid though. Personally I'd have kept your answer... it makes valid points.

Comment: ah so you flip around the which would be the key? In this case DisplayName is the key and TimeZoneInfo is everything else. By doing this way is it faster then doing a foreach loop? It seems like it would be not to mention less code.

Comment: Yes, a dictionary has O(1) access, which is faster than a foreach (which is O(n)) - but more importantly, we only access the data once - contrast with calling GetSystemTimeZones() which might create objects per call. The ToDictionary line creates a dictionary using the DisplayName as the indexed key.

Answer (score 1):

If you use LINQ you can do this:

```
var tz = "(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)";
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single (t => t.DisplayName == tz);
Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} | DisplayName: {1} | SupportsDaylightSavingTime: {2}"
    , tzi.Id, tzi.DisplayName, tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
```