# Get Time Zones list in c#

Tags: c#, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate all time zones in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442019/how-do-i-enumerate-all-time-zones-in-net)

How can I get the list of time zones with c#?
I want a list like the one windows has.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**[GetSystemTimeZones()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx).**

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> tz;
tz= TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

Keep in mind that this returns a [ReadOnlyCollection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)

You can also learn how to populate a list with those timezones [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171251(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: Thank you! And to whoever marked this as a duplicate, please get off your high horse. This was the first result on google. Sorry I don't want to hunt all over the Internet to find an answer someone may have given 10 years ago.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

```
TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
```